# Patch function which calls .Call

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

My goal is to patch the `rlang::eval_tidy` function. In its [original form](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/0a8e00a9a749cb8e4e10c2b00c4fe7d122e1c063/R/eval-tidy.R#L152) it only calls `.Call`:

```r
eval_tidy <- function(expr, data = NULL, env = caller_env()) {
  .Call(rlang_eval_tidy, expr, data, env)
}
```

In my case it should behave different for one single type of value. Therefore, I've changed it to a multi-method where I can add my custom behavior:

```r
package <- getNamespace('rlang')
unlockBinding('eval_tidy', package)
package$eval_tidy <- function(expr, data=NULL, env=caller_env()) UseMethod('eval_tidy', data)
lockBinding('eval_tidy', package)
eval_tidy.custom.value <- function(expr, data, env) ....
eval_tidy.default <- function(expr, data, env) .Call(rlang_eval_tidy, expr, data, env)
```

Now it works like intended for my custom data type, but if another data type is used, I get the following error:

> NotImplementedError: Error in eval_tidy.default(X[[i]]) : object
>   'rlang_eval_tidy' not found

Answer (score 1):

That's because `rlang_eval_tidy` is a compiled object that is [not exported](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/26bf207ac1c2674c39bb951652b319e8a3ab1d7c/src/internal/eval-tidy.c#L469) (and thus not visible) outside of `rlang`. You don't really need to overwrite the package definitions. Just define your custom implementation as a layer on top:

```
eval_tidy <- function(expr, ...) UseMethod('eval_tidy')
eval_tidy.custom <- function(expr, ...) cat("Running custom eval\n")
eval_tidy.default <- function(expr, ...) rlang::eval_tidy(expr, ...)

e1 <- quote(1+1)
eval_tidy(e1)
# [1] 2

class(e1) <- "custom"
eval_tidy(e1)
# Running custom eval
```